# How to live stream locations in swift? Example like uber, lyft etc

Tags: swift, stream, location

I am working on a personal project, and the idea of being able to see where other members in the app were at the moment or if they were moving, but trying to share live locations has been becoming a little challenge, and store data as it goes on a databases i dont think is the right approach or am i wrong? I know theres an sdk called pubnub.... any ideas?

Comment: The PubNub DevRel team is currently building open source examples for this with React Native and also Swift. I will share a link to the example Swift code once it is completed.

Answer (score 0):

going with bidirectional communication sockets would be better choice . go for couchbase , couchDB , etc